# Create Script update from Select statement

Tags: sql

i have a  table in any database. I want to create update script to update in all database from select statement. Anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: help you with what? what is your question about this?

Comment: i'm writing a tool to update. this tool will create a script update to update in anothor database

Comment: Do you have same table In Each DB

Comment: i have same table in other database. so i need create script to update it

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Add sample table data (both tables), before and after the "script" execution.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

`table1` has `column_id1`,`column_id2`

`table2` has `column_id2`,`column_id1`

To update value of `column_id2 = 10` in `table2`, we can try the below

```
update table2 set column_id2 = 10 where column_id1 in 
    (select column_id1 from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @string varchar(Max),@Strt int,@End int

    SELECT Name,Database_Id INto #temp  FROM sys.databases WHERE sys.databases.database_id>4
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()Over(ORDER BY #temp.Database_Id)Rownum,*INTO #Temp1 FROM #temp With(NOLOCK)

    SET @strt=1
    SELECT @End=Max(Rownum)FROM #temp1 

    WHILE @strt<=@End
        BEGIN
         DECLARE @DB Varchar(255)
         SELECT @DB=Name FROM #temp1 With(NOLOCK) WHERE Rownum=@strt

         Set @string ='Update '+@DB+'..TableName Set ColumnName=''XYZ'' from TableName1 Where CloumnName=''ABC'''
         PRINT @string
         Execute (@string)
         SET @strt=@strt+1
        END

    DROP TABLE #temp
    DROP TABLE #Temp1

ROLLBACK    TRAN
```

Comment: This Query Will Update your Table Column 1 by 1 in All Database